# Issue with Windows 10 Lock Screen Shutdown

Tags: windows-10, power-management, lid

I have built a Windows 10 Enterprise image that is being deployed to a combination slate/laptop device (Dell Inspiron 11 - 3153). I am specifying the power settings through SCCM 2012 R2.

I have built a power plan that includes the "Shut Down" behavior for Lid Close. This works perfectly any time I am at the login prompt with no one logged in. However, if a user has locked the screen with their session still open, Windows is ignoring this setting, and putting the laptop into sleep or hibernate instead.

I can't for the life of me find any setting that would determine this. I would ideally like it to ignore any open sessions and perform a forced shutdown if the lid is closed. I can choose to shut down from the software power button on the lock screen, but I can't seem to get it to kill the session by closing the lid. This includes waiting for upwards of 12 hours with the lid closed and power disconnected.

I also know that the screen isn't just showing the last logged in user, since I have the "Don't display last logged on user" setting turned on, and I can log in as Administrator and see the open session.

Does anyone have any advice for how to get around this issue, or know of a setting that I am missing?

Edit: This issue was also blocking shutdown attempts by clicking the PC's hardware power button, which was also set to "Shut Down".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a setting that seems to have solved the issue for me.

Windows 10 (and some older versions) has hidden Power Options under the following registry key:

HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings

Under there, you can see a bunch of different keys. They are organized in the same manner as the settings you see in "Change Advanced Power Settings" under an individual Power Plan's settings. I found a key with the description "Power buttons settings and configurations", and under that was another key (833a6b62-dfa4-46d1-82f8-e09e34d029d6) which had the description "Enable forced shutdown for button and lid actions".

There is two options from here. If you want to make this option appear in Power Options -> Advanced Settings, you need to change the "Attributes" REG_DWORD value to 2 instead of 1. If you want to change whether the setting is enabled or not for your power plans, you need go to each key under DefaultPowerSchemes and flip the values AcSettingIndex (plugged in) and DcSettingIndex (not plugged in) to 1 instead of 0.

I've included a reference to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt608288(v=vs.85).aspx) here, which should help explain it better.

If anyone sees an issue with using this setting, or if anyone has a better idea, I'm all ears. For now, this seems to get around the special settings that apply on the lock screen, but I have no idea why the lock screen is set to behave differently than a logged in user anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 solution:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347\833a6b62-dfa4-46d1-82f8-e09e34d029d6]
"Attributes"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347\833a6b62-dfa4-46d1-82f8-e09e34d029d6\DefaultPowerSchemeValues\381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e]
"ACSettingIndex"=dword:00000001
"DCSettingIndex"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347\833a6b62-dfa4-46d1-82f8-e09e34d029d6\DefaultPowerSchemeValues\8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c]
"ACSettingIndex"=dword:00000001
"DCSettingIndex"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347\833a6b62-dfa4-46d1-82f8-e09e34d029d6\DefaultPowerSchemeValues\a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a]
"ACSettingIndex"=dword:00000001
"DCSettingIndex"=dword:00000001
```

By setting "Attributes" to 2, the option will appear in the power settings menu, and the other entries will set the default values for the Windows 11 builtin power plans.

The current values can be set with powercfg:

```
# balanced
powercfg /setacvalueindex 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 833a6b62-dfa4-46d1-82f8-e09e34d029d6 1
powercfg /setdcvalueindex 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 833a6b62-dfa4-46d1-82f8-e09e34d029d6 1

# high performance
powercfg /setacvalueindex 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 833a6b62-dfa4-46d1-82f8-e09e34d029d6 1
powercfg /setdcvalueindex 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 833a6b62-dfa4-46d1-82f8-e09e34d029d6 1

# power saver
powercfg /setacvalueindex 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 833a6b62-dfa4-46d1-82f8-e09e34d029d6 1
powercfg /setdcvalueindex 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 833a6b62-dfa4-46d1-82f8-e09e34d029d6 1
```